# Proving if crossing line is above function, second derivative is non-negative

Tags: derivatives

Let’s assume $f$ is two times differentiable at all real numbers, and for any $a$ and $b$ that $a<b$, $f$ at $(a, b)$ is under the line drawn between $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$.

How could we prove that for any real $x$, the second derivative at $x$ is non negative?

Comment: Are you familiar with convex functions?

Comment: In fact, I wanted to derive that the second derivative is non negative from knowing that the function is convex upward.

Comment: Hint: show that the  first derivative in increasing: if $x<y$ compare $\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}x$ with $\frac {f(y+h)-f(y)}x$ for. small positive values of $h$.